# Make a selectable html table with objects as values

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am been trying to create a html table that is populated by objects.

The table was supposed to be selectable by row (via hover), when the row was hovered over a function ran.

The table headers are in an array:

```
var topTitles = ["Type","Origin","Destination","T","A","G"];
```

all the data are sitting inside arrays,

```
var Type = [];
var Origin = [];
var Destination = [];
var T = [];
var A = [];
var G = [];
```

I tried to modify an example piece of code, but it was very difficult to conceptualize it and place it into a programatic solution. What is an easy way to map such data directly into a interactive table.

```
function createTable() {
  var table = document.getElementById('matrix');
  var tr = addRow(table);

  for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
    var td = addElement(tr);
    td.setAttribute("class", "headers");
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(topTitles[j]));
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
    var tr = addRow(table);
    var td = addElement(tr);
    td.setAttribute("class", "origin");
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(mode[i]));
    for (var j = 0; j < topTitles.length; j++) {
      var td = addElement(tr, 'element-' + i + '-' + j);
      td.onmouseover = getRouteFunction(i,j);
      td.onclick = getRouteFunction(i,j);
    }
  }
}
function populateTable(rows) {
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < rows[i].elements.length; j++) {
      var distance = rows[i].elements[j].distance.text;
      var duration = rows[i].elements[j].duration.text;
      var td = document.getElementById('element-' + i + '-' + j);
      td.innerHTML = origins[i] + "<br/>" + destinations[j];
    }
  }
}

if (highlightedCell) {
  highlightedCell.style.backgroundColor="#ffffff";
}
highlightedCell = document.getElementById('element-' + i + '-' + j);
highlightedCell.style.backgroundColor="#e0ffff";
showValues();
}
```

Comment: The HTML Table Element (<table>) represents tabular data [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the easiest way I could think of building the table without changing your data structure and make it very clear where all the data is coming from.  It is defiantly not the best code, but it should work for your situation.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LkmEOQ)

```
var topTitles = ["Type","Origin","Destination","T","A","G"];
var Type = ["Type1", "type2", "type3"];
var Origin = ["Origin1", "origin2", "origin3"];
var Destination = ["Destination1", "Destination2", "dest3"];
var T = ["t1", "t2","T3"];
var A = ["steaksauce", "a2", "a3"];
var G = ["G1", "G2", "G3"];
var appendString = [];
for(var i =0; i < topTitles.length; i++){
  if(!i){
    appendString.push("<tr><td>" + topTitles[i] + "</td>");
  }
  else if(i === topTitles.length -1){
    appendString.push("<td>" + topTitles[i] + "</td></tr>");
  }
else{
  appendString.push("<td>" + topTitles[i] + "</td>");
    }
}
for(var i =0; i < Type.length; i++){
    appendString.push("<tr><td>" + Type[i] + "</td><td>" + Origin[i] + "</td><td>" + Destination[i] + "</td><td>" + T[i] + "</td><td>" + A[i] + "</td><td>" + G[i] + "</td></tr>");     
}
var table = document.getElementById('table');
table.innerHTML = appendString.join('');
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear example @JD E, but how would you get the highlight effect implemented? I was hoping to highlight a cell and then run the ShowValue() function

Comment: You could have each td element have the onmouseover event

`<td onmouseover="ShowValue()">`

Which means you could write a function

`function hightlightAndShowValue(){
this.className += "highlightclass";
ShowValue();}
`

and the of course we want to clean up after ourselves so.  

`<td onmouseover="hightlightAndShowValue()" onmouseout="RemoveHighlight()">

function RemoveHighlight(){
this.className = "";
}
`

Comment: this is probably a better remove class function.


`function RemoveClass(){
this.className = this.className.replace("highlight", "");
}`

Comment: I really appreciate the explanation, but I am having a hard time implementing the highlight and mouse over function into your overall code. Could you please update your answer to include that in your CodePen as well. Thank you!